# ُEvery-time I RUN the script it publishes the first row only again and again form the csv file

Tags: python, csv, selenium-webdriver

I write a script to upload images to a website from a CSV file but every time I run the script it uploads only the first row please help.
This is part of the script.
I need to publish all images, descriptions, tags, titles, and colors from the CSV file

```
filename = 'img.csv'
line_number = 1
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    mycsv = csv.reader(f)
    mycsv = list(mycsv)
    images = mycsv[line_number][0]
    titels = mycsv[line_number][1]
    tags = mycsv[line_number][2]
    descriptions = mycsv[line_number][3]
    colors = mycsv[line_number][4]
    
    
    for line in mycsv:
        driver.get('https://www.redbubble.com/portfolio/images/')
        time.sleep(3)
        
        #scroll down
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,400)")


        #click color element
        color = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='global-background-color-setting']//div[@class='sp-replacer sp-light']")
        color.click()

        #click element to writr color code
        color = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='sp-container sp-light sp-buttons-disabled sp-palette-buttons-disabled sp-palette-disabled']//input[@type='text']")
        color.click()
        color.clear()
        color.send_keys(colors)

        time.sleep(2)
        #click element to writr titel
        titel = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='work_title_en']")
        titel.click()
        titel.clear()
        titel.send_keys(titels)


        time.sleep(1)
        #click element to writr tag
        tag = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//textarea[@id='work_tag_field_en']")
        tag.click()
        tag.clear()
        tag.send_keys(tags)

        time.sleep(2)
        #click element to writr descriptions
        description = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//textarea[@id='work_description_en']")
        description.click()
        description.clear()
        description.send_keys(descriptions)

        time.sleep(2)
        # Upload image
        upload = "//input[@id='select-image-base']"
        upload = driver.find_element("xpath",(upload))
        #file path specified with send_keys
        time.sleep(2)
        upload.send_keys(images)
```

Comment: please read your post

Comment: I mean...you need to raise line number no? line_number += 1

Comment: hi can you please write it to me I write "line_number += 1" but it seems not to work

Answer (score 0):

try
images = mycsv[line_number][0: limit of row numbers]

Comment: I have this error message

  `  images = mycsv[line_number][0: limit of row numbers]
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: sorry for that..try changing the line number that you put at the top 'line_number = 1' try changing the '1' to a different number

Comment: try doing something like this 'images = mycsv[line_number][0]' change the '0' to something else